# "cannot open display" error in Ubuntu using VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu (13.10) on a Virtulabox/VM running in Windows 8 and am getting errors whenever I try to run a gui program via the terminal:

> (google-chrome:13377): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
>   127.0.0.1:10.0

A similar error is displayed when I try to run firefox via the terminal.

I have tried numerous attempts to fix this (setting $DISPLAY variable, installing X11, running as root, etc.) and nothing has worked.

Comment: What are you using on Windows 8? Putty or any other tool?

Comment: I have port forwarding and then connect via putty.